# Server 2012 slow performance on ESXi 5.5

Tags: performance, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, navision

I'm having performance issues with a virtual Server 2012 that is installed on an ESXi 5.5 (HP-ESXi-5.5.0-iso-5.71.3). The hardware server is an HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8.

[image: specs]

The server 2012 is acting as an SQL Server (SQL 2008 R2) that is used by Navision. Users are complaining about slow performance. When they want to generate a list in Navision it takes at least a few second, but with the old server (SERVER2003, Not virtual) it only took a second.

- The Server2012 has 24GB of ram, 20480MB Reserved
- 1 Virtual socket, 4 cores per socket. CPU Shares = High, reservervation = 6000Mhz.

In Windows, the taskmanager is showing a constant 98-100% use of the CPU. Also, the memory use is very high. However, perfmon is showing less CPU usage.

[image: Taskmanager]
[image: Perfmon]

The server is not always slow. Most of the time, users are complaining in the morning (Screenshots are taken at this time!). The server has no scheduled tasks, no backups are running. There are the 'Previous Versions', that are made around 07:00, but I don't think this has something to do with each other (Users start complaining as soon as they get in, around 08:00)?

- Windows Power Options are set on 'High Performance'
- A While ago, I've also changed some policy about the encryption between the server and the clients. I Didn't got complaints after that for a few weeks, but now it has returned.
- The mass ammount of users are logging in about 09:00, so it's not that the network is saturated around 08:00.

Comment: I've included multiple screenshots, but it looks like they are not loading.. They are included the right way.

Comment: How large is the database? Are the data and log files on separate virtual disk files and separate from the OS? What RAID level are you using for this LUN?

Comment: What are the specs of the "old server"?

Comment: hi, we have the exact same issue, our windows 2012 hosts running on VMware ESX 5.5 on HP BL460c blades are damn slow. how did you solve it ? (if you did) thanks !